# How to configure CKEditor for Magic Line to activate on other elements?

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, magicline

I've read the [Magic Line plugin documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/magicline.html) but I'm not sure how to add more HTML elements for the plugin to activate with e.g. `<section>`

[image]

I see a way to configure it to activate on all elements:

```
CKEDITOR.config.magicline_everywhere = true;
```

And then to blacklist some elements:

```
CKEDITOR.config.magicline_tabuList = [ 'data-tabu' ];
```

But unsure how to add to the existing default list of HTML elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't possible...from looking at the source code https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/master/plugins/magicline/plugin.js

...it is clear that there is no way to configure/modify the triggers beyond them being either `DTD_BLOCK` (if `magicline_everywhere` is true) or else  `{ table: 1, hr: 1, div: 1, ul: 1, ol: 1, dl: 1, form: 1, blockquote: 1 }` if it is false.

So there appears to be no way to set it to work with an arbitrary list of elements. Also as `<section>` is not a block level element it wouldn't work even if you could add it.